# How to set only one major line in core plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, core-plot

hi i am creating a graph using core plot, i want to change line style for major and minor line ,line style is changed but we have two major line top and bottom line in core plot how to remove top major line

```
- (void) setupGraphAxis: (CPTXYGraph *) graph {
CPTColor *axisColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:0.75];
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = axisColor;


CPTMutableLineStyle *dashLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
dashLineStyle.lineColor = axisColor;
dashLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
dashLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];
dashLineStyle.patternPhase = 0.0f;

CPTMutableLineStyle *fullLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
fullLineStyle.lineColor = axisColor;
fullLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
//fullLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1],nil];
fullLineStyle.lineCap = 0;
fullLineStyle.patternPhase = 0.0f;

//Configure x-axis
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) graph.axisSet;

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.axisLineStyle = nil;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
x.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
x.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
CPTAxisLabelingPolicy policy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
x.labelingPolicy = policy;
x.labelTextStyle = nil;
x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 1;


CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle = nil;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.majorGridLineStyle = fullLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle = dashLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = policy;
y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `labelExclusionRanges` property of the axis to tell it to skip over certain values when creating ticks, grid lines, and labels. If you still want ticks and/or labels at that point, you might need to add another invisible y-axis that only draws the grid lines and let the original y-axis draw everything else.